National Flags using Playing Cards
I have formed some of the national flags using playing cards of suits hearts and clubs.

13 cards of hearts are arranged as follows:


Using these cards,


13 cards of clubs are arranged as follows:


Using these cards,


Using the above logics, can you work out which two national flags would replace the question marks?



PS: I have used the well-known flag of a country for wide audience instead of the recent one. It is purely for puzzling purpose. No offence is intended to anyone.

Note: Depending on something, there can be another national flag for the first among the three equations that has used cards of hearts.

Hint 1:

 If I use a single card in an equation instead of summation of cards, then depending on which single card it is, there are two possibilities. 1) Formation of more than one national flag for that equation. 2) Formation of no national flag at all.


Hint 2:

 


Hint 3:

 Each card is worth two characters.


Is it time for a hint? I've an idea of what it is about, but can't make it work.

@WeatherVane Thanks for the interest. I have added a hint.

I wanted to ask about the middle of the clubs. Is it definitely supposed to be '4 plus 8' and not '4 plus 5'?

@hexomino I think I know why you are getting this doubt. But all the equations are supposed to be what I meant them to be.

Been thinking about this one for a while :) I got one question though, is there some non-trivial knowledge required? I've went in many different directions that requires non-trivial knowledge... but unsure if that's the way to go (since no knowlege-tag).

@Prim3numbah No. No non-trivial knowledge is required at all. It's more like a code. Whole puzzle hinges on figuring out what each card is a substitute of. And ultimately you have to relate this to the given countries.

Neither of the two hints have added anything beyond the original problem statement. In trying to work backward from what I think the theme might be, I see no pattern. Is this one of those number sequences that is only guessable if you know it?

@WeatherVane Nothing to do with number sequences. I have used 13 cards to resemble something.

Your comments are getting votes, but the question has always said the cards are 'arranged', which I took to mean a 'sequence'. In comments you mention 'code', and now 'resemble'. I hope someone can crack your code / resemblance, but after four days still seems to be obscure.

Just a little reminder that comments can easily be taken the wrong way. We wouldn't want a puzzle writer to feel anything other than appreciated. Enjoying the challenge of cracking this one so +1 from me.

@WeatherVane It can still be a sequence that resembles something as a whole. Just not the number sequence for sure.

@sean47 Wow. Thanks. Means a lot. I didn't expect it to become so complex for the community to solve but I thought I had an interesting idea before posting this puzzle. Let's see how this progresses.

In both the clubs and the hearts examples there is a card used twice. Likewise in the puzzle: two of the cards were used in the examples. Is the 'resemblance' consistent? And are there two independent puzzles here, as you originally stated that the clubs and hearts use a different logic?

@WeatherVane The use of only one card twice in both the examples is coincidental. If the examples continued for hearts and clubs, you would have seen more instances of cards replicating. And since one national flag appears in both hearts and clubs, it most certainly suggests two different themes.

@sean47 yes, it's because of my interest that I've been probing.

The space of possible things that the cards and flags could stand for (culture? language? politics? geography? vexillology? something else?) is a bit too big. Can you help us narrow it down?

@codewarrior0 I previously asked if the duplicate use of cards (such as 6♣, 8♣, 1♥, 2♥ and 10♥) was consistent in the examples, hints and questions, but was told it is 'coincidental'. Do I take that as a 'no'?

@codewarrior0 I have added another hint. If someone doesn't answer even after this hint, I will tell what it's about.

The flags you're looking for are:

   The flag of Tajikistan, corresponding to the hearts equation.   and     The flag of Belize corresponding to the clubs equation.

The 13 cards represent, in order:

 Ace=AB  2=CD  3=EF  4=GH  5=IJ  6=KL  7=MN  8=OP  9=QR  10=ST  Jack=UV  Queen=WX  King=YZ

The two suits

 Heart: represents the letters in the name of the country  Clubs: represents the letters in the name of the capital.

So, for the equations containing hearts we got:

 AB + CD = C A M B O D I  A - where we can see that both letter strings are in order (A before B, and C before D)  GH + ST = A F G H A N I S T A N - where both letter strings are in order (G before H, and S before T)  ST + YZ = K Y R G Y Z S T A N - where both letter strings are in order (S before T, and Y before Z)

And for the equations containing clubs, we got:

  AB + KL = K A B U L - where both letters strings are in order (A before B, and K before L)  GH + OP = C O P E N H A G E N - here OP is in order but not GH (but they're there)  KL + ST = S T O C K H O L M - where both letter strings are in order (K before L, and S before T)

Now, solving the two equations...

...we want to check for a country that contains IJ + ST which must be equal to T A J I K I S T A N - here IJ is not in order (but adjacent).  And we want to check for a capital that contains AB + MN + OP which must be equal to B E L M O P A N which is the capital of Belize - here they're all in order except AB (but they're there).


Amazing answer. So to make the rule more concise, the order of the clued-letters in the solution-words are irrelevant, right?

@BenjaminWang Yes. That's how I had designed.
